# How to extract non zero values from an image?

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

i want to extract lines from a text document. I can accomplish this by summing its columns and produce a 1 dimensional vector (This will be the horizontal projection of the image). This is the image
[image]

```
img = imcomplement(rgb2gray(imread('french.jpg')));
lines = sum(img, 2);
plot(lines);
```

If I plot this I can see that the zero values show the blank spaces and the peaks depict the lines. Here is the plot

[image]

So looking at the plot (and the array) I can tell that the third line is from array index `129:184`. So to extract it I did this

```
test = lines(129:184);
```

It does not seem to work as if I do `imshow(test)` or `imshow(test, [])` It gives the following result. Not exactly the third line.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: One of "test = img(:,129:184);" or test = img(129:184,:); must work. Disclaimer: Not tested.

Comment: as @Divakar says, imshow(i(128:end,:)) gives me last line. (tested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to display the 2D image rather than 1D line:

```
imshow(img(129:184,:))
```

gives you line 129 - 184.